# Data supported by HTML5 Local Storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Can i use a Local Storage object  to store another Local Storage object ?
Thank u in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store any object in Web Storage, as long as you can stringify it. But you have only one instance of localStorage in your browser, so you don't have to ask if you can do that, because you can't create new instances.

Comment: Thank you , i find that i can use JSON.stringify(object) . In my case i'm developping a game so i want to store the game progress for every logged in user ( if a player is in the mid game and accidentally closes the web browser. Once he opens the game again, the game starts from the beginning and the game that the player was playing is lost. In this way, players can resume their game later. )

Comment: So for every user i'll create a new localStorage object but you said that " But you have only one instance of localStorage in your browser, so you don't have to ask if you can do that, because you can't create new instances." So it's not possible to do it ? if not how can'i do it so ? Thank you in advance

Comment: No, you have only one instance of localStorage by browser. Each user of your site will have his own localStorage, I don't understand very well your problem.