# LocalStorage Instance

Tags: html, local-storage

I'm developping a mobile game so i want to store the game progress for every logged in user ( if a player is in the mid game and accidentally closes the web browser. Once he opens the game again, the game starts from the beginning and the game that the player was playing is lost. In this way, players can resume their game later.)

So for every user i'll create a new localStorage object but i get this answer here [Data supported by HTML5 Local Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269334/data-supported-by-html5-local-storage/10270105#10270105)  by "Jocelyne lecopmte" .

So it's not possible to do it ? if not how can'i do it so ? Thank you in advance

Comment: You are aware that local storage lives *locally* inside every player's browser? It is not shared among multiple browsers or your server. So every local storage would (in the most natural case) only store this one player's data.

Comment: So i can't do it with LocalStorage , it's a mobile game so naturally i have only one user (the mobile's owner) : so one instance of LocalStorage . Thank u

Answer (score 3):

That will work fine for any single player aspects of the game. You can use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to save and load objects from `localStorage`.

```
var object = new Object();
object.score = 100;
object.name = "John";

localStorage.setItem("player1", JSON.stringify(object));
var copy = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("player1"));

console.log(copy.name);
```

Working code can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yXzKg/1/).

Comment: This helped me with an issue I was having, and solved it perfectly. Thank you.